# ANSIBLE - getting output from command and assign to ansible replace command

Tags: replace, ansible

I'm trying to get the value of value.txt which I think works well in ansible, the file value looks exactly like this

```
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-45]$ cat value.txt 
this-is-the-value
```

I would like to assign the output value as the replacement of the **"CHANGE_ME"** keywords from file.txt

```
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-45]$ cat file.txt 
asdasdh kajsdlkjasdlk CHANGE_ME ajsdlkjasdlkjasd
asdkjhakjsd: CHANGE_ME
jasdlkjadsl{
  aksldjlkasd: CHANGE_ME
}
```

I'm using this ansible playbook to combine the 2 process however it seems it doesn't replace the the **"CHANGE_ME"** when I try to verify the file.txt

```
  - name: check output
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: false
    tasks:
    - name: cat the file
      shell: "cat value.txt"
      register: cat_value
    - debug: var=cat_value.stdout

    - name: modify file.txt
      replace:
        regexp: "{{ cat_value.stdout }}"
        replace: "CHANGE_ME"
        path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/file.txt"
```

The OUTPUT goes like this

```
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-45]$ ansible-playbook ansible.yml 
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [check output] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [cat the file] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "cat_value.stdout": "this-is-the-value"
}

TASK [modify file.txt] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-45]$ cat file.txt
asdasdh kajsdlkjasdlk CHANGE_ME ajsdlkjasdlkjasd
asdkjhakjsd: CHANGE_ME
jasdlkjadsl{
  aksldjlkasd: CHANGE_ME
}
```

Comment: change it to `regexp: "CHANGE_ME"` `replace: "{{ cat_value.stdout }}"`, no?

Comment: ouch! how come I missed to test that. Thanks KamilCuk, it worked out